# Count only if not in array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, select

I have an collections of documents in which I have an array:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5b602207a2f56b05028038c1"
  },
  "groupId": "5b32929cfc37de04f3ce9004",
  "updated": 20180731084703,
  "data": {
    "type": "WallStory",
    "playerId": "5b6003ca031f5bc44d59bb7b",
    "time": "0847",
    "story": "This is my new atory...",
    "reads": [
      "5b6003ca031f5bc44d59bb7b"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is to count all documents which do not have the users id in the "reads" array. I am not sure how to accomplished this?

I am thinking something like this, but am not succesfull:

```
var newStories = 0;
newStories += dbCollection('groupWallStories').count({"groupId": "5b32929cfc37de04f3ce9004", "data.reads": thisUserId }).sort({"updated": -1}).limit(10);
```

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Show a sample of your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get better performance from a simple [`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) query with [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator

```
dbCollection('groupWallStories').count({ "data.reads": { "$ne": thisUserId } })
```

Or with the aggregation you can use   [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) here:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$setIsSubset": [
              [ "5b6003ca031f5bc44d59bb7b" ],
              "$data.reads"
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You also need to "cast" using `id` from the "string" to a valid `ObjectId` in aggregation

Comment: Perfect... Works like a charm :-)